# Using jQuery, how do I get the first parent element found with a selection of text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following element assigned to a variable, along with a set of selection indexes for this variable.

```
var html_element = $("<p>Some text goes <b>here</b> then continues here</p>").appendTo("body");
var start = 15;
var end = 17;
```

This SHOULD represent the letters "her" in the word "here". Is there any way for me to use these indexes and the html_element to get the first HTML element (parent) of the selection...? So in this case I want to grab "**here**" as a jQuery object.

So that if I want I can change the text "here" to anything such as "new here".

In plain terms I want to grab the first element before the start_index.

Comment: pls can you specify more clear what you want? I guess so parent of html_element is body

Comment: You could just use a regex and replace the first match.

Comment: you want grab first html element before start index?

Comment: @Yatrix That wouldn't work because something I would also like to do is change the class of b to something else. I'm also thinking that if for some reason i had multiple elements using the word <b>here</b> and i try to change the second that it will cause the first to change not the second one.

Comment: @daremachine yes daremachine, the first element before start index.

Comment: _"I have the following element assigned to a variable, along with a set of selection indexes for this variable. This SHOULD represent the letters "her" in the word "here"."_ Using which methods ? What character would be at index `0` of `html_element` as string ?

Comment: You want to select the innermost element that start and end are within?

Comment: The letter 's' would be.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour yes Majid.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `:contains()` to select element containing characters within `html_element` at indexes `15` through `17`; `.text()`, `String.prototype.slice()`

```js
var html_element = $("<p>Some text goes <b>here</b> then continues here</p>")
                   .appendTo("body");

var start = 15;
var end = 17;
// element containing charaters at parent element text indexes 15 through 17
var selected = $(":contains(" + html_element.text().slice(15, 17) + ")"
               , html_element); // set `context` to `html_element`
// set new text at `selected`
selected.text(function(_, text) {
  return "new " + text
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

alternatively, `.contents()` , `for` loops to count characters of text nodes with `p` element

```js
var html_element = $("<p>Some text goes <b>here</b> then continues here</p>")
  .appendTo("body");

var start = 15;
var end = 17;

var text = 0;
var elem = null;
var contents = html_element.contents();

for (var index = 0; index < contents.length; index++) {
  var el = contents[index];
  if (elem === null && (el.nodeType === 3 || el.firstChild.nodeType === 3)) {
    var txt = el.textContent || el.nodeValue;
    for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
      text += 1;
      if (text >= start + 1 && text <= end) {
        elem = $(el)
        break
      }
    };
  } else {
    break;
  }
};

console.log(elem, text, text >= start && text <= end);

elem.text(function(_, txt) {
  return "new " + txt
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: I thought something like this would work, and I'm still considering it. The only issue is that if html_element contains two identical elements <b>here</b> in two different spots, and the second spot is the one being selected, it would return the first one in this case... But still the best answer so far.

Comment: @Ricky _"The only issue is that if html_element contains two identical elements <b>here</b> in two different spots, and the second spot is the one being selected, it would return the first one in this case"_ Yes, that would be result. You could elements results to first match, or any matched element in collection of elements using `.eq()` or `.filter()` , depending on expected results. Is requirement to select only first element having specific text ? Another approach would be to iterate all text nodes

Comment: @Ricky  Added alternative approach using `.contents()` , `for` loops, see updated post

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace the contents of the `<b><\b>` tag, you can do something like this:

```
html_element.find('b').text('My custom Text');
```

Comment: No I can't do that because the b tag was just an example, there may not even be a b tag in which case we would go to the root, the p tag, also the b tag might be something else... like an i tag.